# Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1626

Tags: php, wordpress

Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1626
No such file or directory

**When I post a blog on my wordpress website, I m getting same error again & again. After few minutes it's fix automaticaaly.**

I don't know exaclty. What is the problem.

Please Give me solution step by step.

I am beginner in WordPress.

Comment: What is on line 1626?

Comment: 1626 line:        mysqli_real_connect( $this->dbh, $host, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, null, $port, $socket, $client_flags );

Comment: Based on that information, I would assume that the `$this` object has not been defined until later in the code which is why it works later and not right away. I hope that helps direct you to the issue.

Comment: Thank @Mech.   But Could you tell me how to implement which you mention above. I don't expert in programming.